# Is the looting honour penalty permanent in Shogun 2 Total War?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

If your clan loots a province, your daimyo gets a -1 to his Honour rating.  Does this ever go away, or does it last for the rest of the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the honor of a Daimyo is his own. When that Daimyo dies, and is replaced the things that he has done won't so much effect the new one.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't last for the rest of the game, only until the daimyo dies and his heir succeeds him.  So if you want to do dishonorable things, have a geezer do it and blame it on his senility. :P